# chart.js barchart without set fill color

Tags: javascript, charts, bar-chart, chart.js

This is my first time using Chart.js and I want to create bar chart with multiple series. Based on documentation we have to specify fillColor for each dataset.
Is that possible to create multiple chart without set fillColor (like barchart in excel).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

fillColor uses rgba. a = alpha. you can set alpha value to 0. such as

```
fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0)"
```

this should give it a transparent fill color and still display the border colors assuming you have them not transparent.

Answer (score 2):

I know its very late, but we can achieve empty bar chart with only the border visible by setting the property : `fill:false`

Hope it helps someone :)